# Zend update row

Tags: database, zend-framework

I have a button, when that button is click it will update a row by +1.

It doesn't work it only update to 1 in the database table, the next time i click it won't goes to 2, it stay at 1. I want it, everytime i click it increment the number by 1.

Here's the funstion in model:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Row_User extends Sayka_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
    public function grantDiscount()
    {
        $this->has_discount = has_discount + 1;
                // $this->has_discount++; <- not working too, only increment to 1.
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_buy_now']))
{
     $user->grantDiscount();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually don't use the `DbTable_Row` object in this manner myself but I think your function should look like:

```
<?php
class Application_Model_DbTable_Row_User extends Sayka_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
    public function grantDiscount()
    {
        /*row object->column->has_discount = row object->column->has_discount +1*/
        $this->has_discount = $this->has_discount + 1;

        $this->save();
        /*returning the row object may or may not be important or helpful in this case.*/
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `save()` returns the primary key(s) of the row inserted/updated or an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any difference between Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract and Sayka_Db_Table_Row_Abstract? Probably it replaces zend original magic methods __get and __set.